# ModernCV class does not compile in Debian 9 (Stretch)

Tags: fancyhdr, moderncv, package-options

In my previously installed `Debian Jessie` everything went fine with `ModernCV`-files, but now in `Debian Stretch` I always receive the following error:

`\fancyfoot's 'E' option without twoside option is useless`

Any ideas on how to solve this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a *warning* emitted by the [`fancyhdr`](https://ctan.org/pkg/fancyhdr) package, that the use of the `E` option has no effect in single-sided mode.

This is just a warning and not an error. It can be safely ignored; if your document is failing to compile, it is not because of this.

Alternatively, you can remove the `E` option to prevent this warning (as mentioned by [David Carlisle](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/1090/david-carlisle) in his [comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/435293/moderncv-class-does-not-compile-in-debian-9-stretch#comment1091487_435293)).

Note that this is not related to your operating system or any particular software packages, except your version of [TeX Live](https://ctan.org/pkg/texlive), which now (presumably) includes an updated version of `fancyhdr`.